# How do GLCanvas and JFrame work together?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have this simple first program which runs correctly.

```
public class OpenGL extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {

    GLCanvas glCanvas;

    public OpenGL() {
        setTitle("First OpenGL Program");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocation(0, 0);
        glCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        glCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        this.add(glCanvas);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new OpenGL();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure what the following lines of code do:

```
glCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
this.add(glCanvas);
```

Comment: Which library is this? You need to say whether you are using JOGL, LWJGL3, LWJGL 2 etc....

Comment: @nedb Hi, I’m using JOGL.

Answer (score -1):

I found a good explanation of my question [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/jogl2.0.html#zz-3.2)